# How do I use the values (read from a .ps1 file) to update the values of another .ps1 file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a `4.ps1` file that looks like this

```
#akabradabra
$one = 'o'

#bibi
$two = 't'

$three = 't'              #ok thr


#four
$four = 'four'
```

And a `3.ps1` file that looks like this

```
#akabradabra
$one = 'one'

#biblibablibo
$two = 'two'

$three = 'three'              #ok threer
```

My goal is to read the key-value pair from `4.ps1` and update the values in `3.ps1` and if new key-value pairs are introduced in `4.ps1`, simply append them to the end of `3.ps1`.

My idea is to use string functions such as `.Split('=')` and `.Replace(' ', '')` to extract the keys and if the keys match, replace the entire line in `3.ps1` with the one found in `4.ps1`

I know that using `Get-Variable` might does the trick and also it will be a lot easier to work with the data if I convert all the key-value pairs into a `.xml` or a `.json` file but can anyone please show me how can I make it work in my own silly way?

Here is my code to do so

```
# Ignore this function, this is used to skip certain key-value pairs
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function NoChange($something) {

    switch ($something) {

        '$CurrentPath' {return $true}
        '$pathToAdmin' {return $true}
        '$hostsPathTocompare' {return $true}
        '$logs' {return $true}
        '$LogFile' {return $true}
        default {return $false}

    }
}
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ReadFromVARS = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\4.ps1
$WriteToVARS = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\3.ps1

foreach ($oldVar in $ReadFromVARS) {

    if (('' -eq $oldVar) -or ($oldVar -match '\s*#+\w*')) {
        continue
    } elseif ((NoChange ($oldVar.Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0]))) {
        continue
    } else {
        $var = 0
        #$flag = $false
        while ($var -ne $WriteToVARS.Length) {
            if ($WriteToVARS[$var] -eq '') {
                $var += 1
                continue
            } elseif ($WriteToVARS[$var] -match '\s*#+\w*') {
                $var += 1
                continue
            } elseif ($oldVar.Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0] -eq $WriteToVARS[$var].Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0]<# -and !$flag#>) {
                $oldVar
                $WriteToVARS.replace($WriteToVARS[$var], $oldVar) | Set-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\3.ps1 -Force
                break
                #$var += 1
                #$flag = $true
            } elseif (<#!$flag -and #>($var -eq $WriteToVARS.Length)) {
                Add-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\3.ps1 -Value $oldVar -Force
                $var += 1
            } else {
                $var += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did not ran into any errors but it only updated one key-value pair (`$two = t`) and it did not append new key-value pairs at the end. Here is the result I got

```
#akabradabra
$one = 'one'

#biblibablibo
$two = 't'

$three = 'three'              #ok threer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think [Dot-Sourcing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode-and-the-dot-source-operator/) is what you're after.

*The PowerShell dot-source operator brings script files into the current session scope. It is a way to reuse script. All script functions and variables defined in the script file become part of the script it is dot sourced into. It is like copying and pasting text from the script file directly into your script.*

To make it visible, use Dot-Sourcing to read in the variables from file 3.ps1, show the variables and their values. Next dot-source file 4.ps1 and show the variables again:

```
. 'D:\3.ps1'

Write-Host "Values taken from file 3.ps1" -ForegroundColor Yellow

"`$one   : $one"
"`$two   : $two"
"`$three : $three"
"`$four  : $four"   # does not exist yet

. 'D:\4.ps1'

Write-Host "Values after dot-sourcing file 4.ps1" -ForegroundColor Yellow

"`$one   : $one"
"`$two   : $two"
"`$three : $three"
"`$four  : $four"
```

The result is

> ```
> Values taken from file 3.ps1
> $one   : one
> $two   : two
> $three : three
> $four  : 
> Values after dot-sourcing file 4.ps1
> $one   : o
> $two   : t
> $three : t
> $four  : four
> ```

If you want to write these variables back to a ps1 script file you can:

```
'one','two','three','four' | Get-Variable | ForEach-Object { 
    '${0} = "{1}"' -f $_.Name,$_.Value
} | Set-Content 'D:\5.ps1' -Force
```

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you for providing a new approach to solve this problem but it is not what I was asking. I want my own script to work. I will wait and see if there will be more answers to come. If not, I will opt yours as the answer. Hope you could understand.

Answer (score 0):

**Theo's answer provides a easier way to do the same thing**

**Also, converting your Config files to JSON or XML will make the job lot more easier too**

My original idea was to read both `4.ps1` and `3.ps1` ( these are my config files, I only store variables inside and switch statement to help choosing the correct variables ) then overwrite `3.ps1` with all the difference found but I could not get it working so I created a new `5.ps1` and just simply write everything I need to `5.ps1`.

Here is my code if you would like to use it for your own project :-)

The obstacles for me were that I had `switch` statements and certain `$variables` that I wanted to ignore (in my actual project) so I used some [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6) to avoided it.

```
$ReadFromVARS = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\4.ps1
$WriteToVARS = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\3.ps1
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PSScriptRoot\5.ps1 -Force

Function NoChange($something) {

    switch ($something) {

        '$CurrentPath' {return $true}
        '$pathToAdmin' {return $true}
        '$hostsPathTocompare' {return $true}
        '$logs' {return $true}
        '$LogFile' {return $true}
        default {return $false}

    }
}

$listOfOldVars = @()
$switchStatementStart = "^switch(\s)*\(\`$(\w)+\)(\s)*(\n)*\{"
$switchStatementContent = "(\s)*(\n)*(\t)*\'\w+(\.\w+)+\'(\s)*\{(\s)*\`$\w+(\s)*=(\s)*\@\((\s)*\'\w+(\.\w+)+\'(\s)*(,(\s)*\'\w+(\.\w+)+\'(\s)*)*\)\}"
$switchStatementDefault = "(\s)*(\n)*(\t)*Default(\s)*\{\`$\w+(\s)*=(\s)*\@\((\s)*\'\w+(\.\w+)+\'(\s)*(,(\s)*\'\w+(\.\w+)+\'(\s)*)*\)\}\}"
$switchStatementEnd = "(\s)*(\n)*(\t)*\}"


foreach ($oldVar in $ReadFromVARS) {

    if (('' -eq $oldVar) -or ($oldVar -match '^#+\w*')) {
        continue
    } elseif ((NoChange $oldVar.Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0])) {
        continue
    } else {
        $var = 0
        while ($var -ne $WriteToVARS.Length) {
            if ($WriteToVARS[$var] -eq '') {
                $var += 1
                continue
            } elseif ($WriteToVARS[$var] -match '^#+\w*') {
                $var += 1
                continue
            } elseif ($oldVar -match $switchStatementStart -or $oldVar -match $switchStatementContent -or $oldVar -match $switchStatementDefault -or $oldVar -match $switchStatementEnd) {
                Add-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\5.ps1" -Value $oldVar -Force
                $listOfOldVars += ($oldVar)
                break
            } elseif ($oldVar.Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0] -eq $WriteToVARS[$var].Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0]) {
                Add-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\5.ps1" -Value $oldVar -Force
                $listOfOldVars += ($oldVar.Remove(0,1).Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0])
                break
            } else {
                $var += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($newVar in $WriteToVARS) {
    if ($newVar.StartsWith('#') -or $newVar -eq '') {
        continue
    } elseif ($newVar -match $switchStatementStart -or $newVar -match $switchStatementContent -or $newVar -match $switchStatementDefault -or $newVar -match $switchStatementEnd) {

    } elseif (($newVar.Remove(0,1).Split('=').Replace(' ', '')[0]) -in $listOfOldVars) {
        continue
    } else {
        Add-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\5.ps1" -Value $newVar -Force
    }
}
```